# Count occurrence of integers in ArrayList and return 0 if the number does not occur

Tags: java

I have managed to count occurrences of the integer but I'm having a problem in putting the count of the numbers that do not occur to 0. The numbers will go from 0-99. If the number is in the list, the count will be updated accordingly but if it is not, the count will be 0.

```
public static void freqCount(List<Integer> numbers){
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        Integer prevNumber = null;

        for (int number: numbers) {
            if (prevNumber == null || prevNumber != number) {
                int count = Collections.frequency(numbers, number);
                System.out.println(number + " occurs " + count);
            }
            prevNumber = number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. What are you doing with the `count` variable? This doesn't do anything useful at all.

Comment: I'm trying to output the count which is why I initialize a count variable there.

Comment: You aren't outputting anything. If you want to print the value of `count` you need `System.out.println(count)`

Comment: what count you want and method return type is void? @www

Comment: @MFisherKDX please find edits. It should be clearer now

Comment: @Deadpool please find edits

Comment: Initialize an array of size 100 ints to 0. Then update each element with it's frequency. At the end of the function you have your answer. And the numbers that didn't occur are still 0.

Comment: @www, as MFisherKDX said, you can simply increment an integer array at the index of the current number in your list and after iterating the whole list, you will have an array of counts.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
public static int[] freqCount(List<Integer> numbers) {
    int[] countArr = new int[100];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        countArr[i] = Collections.frequency(numbers, i);
    return countArr;
}
```

This should return the number of occurrences for each number between 0 and 99 inclusive as an array. If a number `n` does not appear in `numbers`, `returnedArray[n]` is zero.